# Check if network is down before starting Jenkins Job

Tags: svn, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

Because of another programme that is running on the same host as my Jenkins, my Networkcard is sometimes temporarily disabled. This causes my Jobs in Jenkins to fail because they should performe an SVN update at the beginning. I installed [naginator](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Naginator+Plugin) which allows me to rebuild the failed jobs later, which works good.

My problem is that each time a job fails an e-mail is generated to all colleagues that have changed something in SVN. Since the main reason for the fails is that the SVN checkout was not successful, these e-mails are being ignored.

Is there a way to check if the Network is aviable before starting a Job? In this way e-mails are sent only if the fail is "real" and will not be ignored anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create another job which will run before your existing job.
It will try to clone the project from SVN, and in case of success trigger your actual job, if clone fails - nothing happens and no one will receive emails.
You'll need to install [Build Pipeline Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Build+Pipeline+Plugin) for that.